# Displaying multiple sql columns in one html column

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a form with multiple checkboxes which are stored as different columns in a database.

I want to display them as a single column in a webpage, how can I do that?

HTML Form:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">R-11</label>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="r11" value="R11">
            </div>
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">E-1</label>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="e1" value="E1">
            </div>
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">E-2</label>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="e2" value="E2">
            </div>
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">E-3</label>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="e3" value="E3">
            </div>
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">L-1</label>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="l1" value="L1">
            </div>
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">R-12</label>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="r12" value="R12">
            </div>
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">C-1</label>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="c1" value="C1">
            </div>
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">C-2</label>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="c2" value="C2">
            </div>
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">C-3</label>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="c3" value="C3">
            </div>
    </div>
```

PHP Code, generating the rows and columns:

```
                <?php 

    while($maininfo=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){

        echo "<tr>";

        echo "<td>".$maininfo['run_number']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$maininfo['date']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$maininfo['station']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$maininfo['time_of_call']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$maininfo['onscene']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$maininfo['inservice']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$maininfo['address']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$maininfo['category1']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$maininfo['category2']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$maininfo['info']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$maininfo['shift']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$maininfo['name']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$maininfo['r11']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$maininfo['e1']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$maininfo['e2']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$maininfo['e3']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$maininfo['l1']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$maininfo['r12']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$maininfo['c1']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$maininfo['c2']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$maininfo['c3']."</td>";

        echo "</tr>";

    }//end while

    ?>
```

I would like the table in the website to show all of the r-11 thru c-3 in one column.  How can I do that?  I have tried merging a couple of them together like:

```
             echo "<td>".$maininfo['r11', 'e1']."</td>";
```

However, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This represents the output from one database column:

```
$maininfo['r11']
```

This is two:

```
$maininfo['r11'] . $maininfo['e1']
```

Wrap those two in an HTML table cell:

```
"<td>" . $maininfo['r11'] . $maininfo['e1'] . "</td>"
```

Repeat as necessary for however you want to design the HTML output.  Add spaces, separators, more HTML markup, etc.

Basically, the values are still individual things.  You simply need to concatenate the output together into the HTML structure you want.  It's not up to the database to do this, or the array structure.  They have their own jobs to do.  It's up to you to build your output strings.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you so much!  I have been looking and looking for an answer, this is great.  I knew it would be simple.

Comment: I also am curious.  The when echoing the date.  It displays it as 2016-01-02.    Is there a way that I can have it display the date format at 01/02/16?

Comment: @AdamCourington: This would be a good place to start: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php  Conversely, you can also format the date in JavaScript on the client-side if you prefer.  There are a number of approaches to take.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td>".$maininfo['r11'].$maininfo['e1']."</td>";
```

Comment: Thank you. This got me pointed in the right direction.  I just had to add a . to the end.